# How to access MongoDB from Matlab?

Tags: java, mongodb, matlab

I'm trying to access mongoDB from Matlab through Java driver, but it seems Matlab could not find MongoClient class.

Here are some error messages from Matlab

> > javaaddpath('mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar');
> >
> > import com.mongodb.*;
> >
> > mc = MongoClient(server, port);

Undefined function or variable 'MongoClient'.

> > import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

Error using import Import argument 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' cannot be found or cannot be imported.

Comment: Try to use the full path instead of a relative path. What version of MATLAB do you use?

Comment: Matlab version : R2015a
I copied jar file to the same directory,  so I didn't use a full path. 
I got the same error message when I used full path

Comment: Did you try using the full path?